# Can't read an Excel file using Pandas. BookView.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'WindowWidth'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to read a df using pandas. But i get the following error:

```py
BookView.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'WindowWidth'
```

This is what i am doing:

This what i've done:

```py
arquivo = pd.read_excel(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite enough information to diagnose further, but I got a similar error, and after renaming the input sheet requested, and then requesting it, I got a successful read.  The input file was .xlsx and changing it to .xls did not work, but specifying the sheet and re saving the file did.  Best of luck!

e.g.:

exported = pd.read_excel(in_blob_path, sheet_name="FooFoo")